# Crosswalk integration with cordova

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, crosswalk-runtime

I have integrated crosswalk with cordova in my ADT project as mentioned in the following 
[URL](https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/cordova/migrate_an_application.html#Migrate-using-ADT)
Do I have to make any other change in my cordova project/Code in order to use crosswalk webview instead of the original android webview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the crosswalk version of cordova there is no change needs to be done in your cordova project.

All you have to do is import https://github.com/crosswalk-project/crosswalk-cordova-android
into eclipse(ADT).

Instead of cordova dependancy in project add crosswalk cordova project.
Your original cordova project now should be using crosswalk webview.

Comment: In this link you can see that this project is deprecated: "This repository is based on Cordova-Android 3.6.3, which is not being maintained upstream anymore".